# How to make the opening of browser(all test in one browser) static in testng for selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am using selenium and testNG framework for my project. 
Now what is happening is each class is opening up a browser and then run its methods, eg, if I have five classes, then five browsers will open simultaneously and then run the tests.
I want to Open Browser at the start once and run all the methods and then close it.

```
public class openSite
{
public static WebDriver driver;
@test
public void openMain()
{
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/drive/chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://vtu.ac.in/");
}
@test
//Clicking on the first link on the page
public void aboutVTU()
{
driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-323")).click();
}
@Test
//clicking on the 2nd link in the page
public void Institutes()
{
driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-325")).click();
}
```

Now What I want is the testNG should open browser once and open vtu.ac.in once and then execute the methods aboutVTU and Institutes and give me the result

Comment: remove `driver` instantiating again in `openMain()` method.You have already declared it as `static`. Use @BeforeClass method to initiate webdriver. remaining else in `@Test`. Go through this http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: I tried that and I am getting nullpointer exception

Comment: remove `webdriver` from this line ` WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` that is the line causing null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already declared the type for `driver` in your field declarations. Redeclaring it in `openMain()` is your problem. It should look like this.

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class OpenSite {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
    public void openMain()
    {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://vtu.ac.in/");
    }

    @Test
    //Clicking on the first link on the page
    public void aboutVTU()
    {
        assertNotNull(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-323")).click();
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods="aboutVTU")
    //clicking on the 2nd link in the page
    public void Institutes()
    {
        assertNotNull(driver);
        driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-325")).click();
    }
}
```